# Simple javascript not working in Shopify

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, shopify

I give up, I can't get this to work even though in the Shopify documentation it says it should. I just need to turn off the loading spinner.

Here is my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ShopifyApp.ready(function(){
  ShopifyApp.Bar.loadingOff();
  });
</script>
```

And then this is the documentation from Shopify:

> ShopifyApp.Bar.loadingOff()
>
> Stops the loading spinner. Should probably be called on every page in
>     ShopifyApp.ready().

There is nothing in the `application.html.erb` file or the `embedded_app.html.erb` file that would override this..

[I found other people with the same issue.](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/shopify-loading-bar-spinner-is-not-complete-after-loading-full-page-successfully-300289)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a key debugging check. Check your console, specifically the console logs for the embedded App iframe. I bet you'll find one of two things.

1. you made a JS error and therefore that code is not running (the code you pasted is correct and does work)
2. there is another process not working, like a connection to a network resource (websocket??)

Anytime some Shopify embedded App code borks, you might see the loading bar go slowly and forever. These events are usually short-lived.

My guess is, you have a JS error in your code, so as soon as you fix that, your loading bar issues will disappear.